# Centering equations doesn't work

Tags: align, gather

I'm new to Latex and trying to center some equations.
The following works:

```
\begin{gather*}
MSE = MSE_{net\_sir} + MSE_{net\_f}\\
\end{gather*}
```

But for some reason this doesn't show when I try to center it:

```
\begin{gather*}
MSE_{net\_sir} = \frac{1}{N_{net\_sir}}\[ \sum_{i=1}^{N_{net\_sir} $\mid net\_sir(time\_array^i) - SIR^i\mid^2 $ \] 
\end{gather*}
```

I tried both `align` and `gather` environments and neither work

Comment: Since the displayed equation contains a single line, there's no use case for `gather*` here. Indeed, `\[ ... \]` will do just as well and, depending on how full the line right above the unnumbered equation is, even better than `\begin{gather*} ... \end{gather*}`.

Comment: you must get an error from using `\[` inside math, if you get _any_ error just look at the log and fix the error don't look at the pdf output.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot guys

Comment: While you need `\{` and `\}` for the braces, the brackets are input just with `[` and `]`. The commands `\[` and `\]` mean completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unpaired group (`{` with no closing `}`), a display math environment within a math context already (`\[`...`\]` within `gather`). Some other elements have also been changed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  MSE_{\mathrm{net\_sir}}
    = \frac{1}{N_{\mathrm{net\_sir}}} 
      \biggl[ \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\mathrm{net\_sir}}} \bigl\lvert \mathrm{net\_sir}(\mathrm{time\_array}^i) - \mathrm{SIR}^i \bigr\rvert^2 \biggr]
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could probably also use `\mathrm{MSE}` as it's more of a term than M × S × E.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: But really, `gather*` shouldn't be used for a single-line display.  `\[...\]` is better.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\biggl[\,` would be better, in my opinion, because it avoids the bracket to clash with the upper limit.